# Remove almost identical data frame rows comparing them R

Tags: r, data-science

I want to know if theres someway to only mantain one row if theres is some other rows that are similar, something that works similar as `stringsim`, doing it between all the roes, and deleting those duplicaste based in that criteria.

Comment: Do you have some threshold for distance

Comment: @akrun I Think that the similarity, its like 80% needed

Comment: It will be easier to help if you can make this a concrete example, ideally with a demonstration of some rows that you evaluate to be on either side of your "80%" threshold. Does "80%" mean each column is 80% similar to a matching column, or that 80% of the columns are exact matches, or something else?

Comment: Also think about if A is 80% similar to B, and B is 80% similar to C, but A and C are only 70% similar... what to keep?